# CSS mask for image grid

Tags: html, css, mask, grid-layout

**How to create an image grid with images nicely lined up in same height rows and same width columns, giving we could have pictures of different aspect ratios in responsive design, in CSS?**

Let's take this example page with grid, it's self-explanatory:
http://destadesign.com/test/capricorn/test.html
The image in second row sticks out of the grid.

Responsive design rather require from us to use **percent(%)** values instead of fixed pixel values, and only for width, so that height is calculated automatically, which in this case complicate things.

I'd think of a **clipping mask(?)** for images to accomplish that (divs of the same size, holding different size images), however I lack the skill for creating such complex CSS. Any specific help would be highly appreciated, but also some general ideas and guidelines would come in handy.

HTML div-imgage boxes has such (rather natural?) structure:

```
<div id="1" class="figure">
  <a href="#" class="link1">        
    <img src="images/pic_mountain.jpg" alt="TARGI W PARYŻU">
    <div class="figcaption">
      <h4>test 1</h4>  
    </div>
  </a>
</div><!-- /end .figure -->
```

CSS with non-essential hover and text-centering effect:

```
.figure {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    left:20px;
   }
     .figure a{
      display:block;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     position:relative;
     z-index:2;
   }
    .figure a img{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    }
.figcaption {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 2;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    transition:all 0.4s ease;

}
.figcaption h4{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.figure a:hover .figcaption {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Please go ahead and use this CodePen for convenience:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GopQPZ

Answer (score 2):

Without using CSS masks, [an example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQbwYK):

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2vw;
}

a {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 10vw;
}
a img {
  height: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="figure1" class="figure">
  <a href="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/8/82727/1525513-the_moutain____by_vincentfavre.jpg" class="link1" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/8/82727/1525513-the_moutain____by_vincentfavre.jpg" alt="TARGI W PARYŻU">
    <div class="figcaption">
      <h4>test 1</h4>  
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="figure2" class="figure">
  <a href="http://www.britishairways.com/cms/global/assets/images/content/760x350_beach_Pod-3.jpg" class="link2" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://www.britishairways.com/cms/global/assets/images/content/760x350_beach_Pod-3.jpg" alt="TARGI W PARYŻU">
    <div class="figcaption">
      <h4>test 2</h4>  
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="figure3" class="figure">
  <a href="http://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/barnesy/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/country_western.jpg" class="link3" target="_blank">        
    <img src="http://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/barnesy/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/country_western.jpg">
    <div class="figcaption">
      <h4>test 3</h4>  
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="figure4" class="figure">
  <a href="http://junebugweddings.com/img/photobug/January2013/beautiful-landscape-wedding-portrait-by-julian-kanz.jpg" class="link4" target="_blank">        
    <img src="http://junebugweddings.com/img/photobug/January2013/beautiful-landscape-wedding-portrait-by-julian-kanz.jpg">
    <div class="figcaption">
      <h4>test 4</h4>  
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: THanks, nice job. I have to admit  I never saw similar "clipping mask" CSS solution like you proposed. Only flaw is those "vw" units that doesn't really add up very good with "%" on site, as they regard to width of the viewport, while "%" regard to parent container which in deep chains of containers behaves quite differently than "vw". Another thing is the image "mask" shows top of the image. I presume the ideal solution should show middles. If this would be possible, such thing should posted somewhere on the web as really precious CSS code bit.

Comment: You will have to play with units, as always :) here viewport units allows to have a the same dimension for height and width. As for the positioning, this is indeed a limit.

Comment: I have combined this with absolute center positioning, so the thumb now shows the center of the image : )

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extremely nice CSS grid that's completely **responsive**. It takes images of any size and you can choose the **amount of columns** and the space between the images. With media queries you can also make it so that the number of columns changes depending on the size of the device.

https://goo.gl/5SFndB

Credit goes to Chris Coyier. I've used that grid a countless amount of times! It's great.

Also, here's a pen from the same post. It's a beauty!

```
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;

   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/pvamyK

Comment: Thanks. Nice responsiveness. However I wouldn't call this a "grid", rather a "waterfall" ;). Images looks chaotic this way, and using a "clipping mask" solution leaves nice structure of even horizontal and vertical lines in grid.